# How do I make Aperture 3 export the master

Tags: apple-aperture, scanner, data-corruption

I've tried many things to get Aperture to export some sort of usable file when I do a "export-> Master"

The command seems to work, it creates a file of the proper name. The output is about 4K in size, and when I try to open it, every programs says is a broken or illegallly formated TIFF file.

I've tried all of the options for including and excluding metadta from the export dialog box. No joy.

What I want is a file similar to the RAW (canon format) or the scanned TIFF file that went in.

Comment: Strange. It has never failed me. I get a copy of the original raw file when exporting.

Comment: works fine for me too. do you have enough diskspace?

Comment: I have tons of space, 200GB+ free

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is not normal. Aperture *should* write the assosiated source file(s) to the directory you specify in the export dialog, depending on the options probably in a subfolder named by the project.

So something goes severly wrong. For troubleshooting I suggest you check the following things:

- Does this happen to all photos or only to one/some?
- Is the photo you want export referenced or local. If refrenced, is it online?
- Can you export the version?
- Does the filesystem of the volume you export to support all charcters  in the file and project name?
- Can you export the file to another location (other folder, other volumne)?

Hope this gets you closer!

Comment: Yes, the version export works fine. I haven't seen any weird characters in the file or project name.

Haven't tried exporting to another location, Good idea.

It happens to all of the images that I've imported from my scanner. I have never seen the problem when I import from my DSLR.

Comment: Interesting: It's only the photos from your scanner - Does it happen to other TIFF files? Scanner files can be very large. Does it happen with small files from your scanner? Can you view them normally in other apps like Preview?

Comment: I'll try that. They are big, but its only a 4000 DPI scan of 35mm slides, its not a scan of a full A1 page of paper.  Not sure which "them" you are asking. I can view the direct from the scanner images in Preview, but the exported from Aperture images are not viewable, they are unrecognized.

Answer (score 0):

Here another way to go about it:

If exporting does not work, you could try to make the file **referenced** (Menu item *File -> Relocate Masters*) and then open the containing directory in Finder (Menu item *File -> Show in Finder*). The master should be in this directory. Now **copy** it to your desired location.

I have tried it. It works for me.